# How can I install a new stylesheet in CDF Player?

Tags: cdf-format

I've created my own stylesheet and I would like to install it in the CDF 9 directory, so when I apply it to a new *Mathematica* notebook and save it as CDF file, it will show it correctly.
I used this path in my computer:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Wolfram Research\Wolfram CDF\Player\9.0\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets`

but it doesn't seem to work.
I tried the same thing with CDF 8 and it works.